# USB automount call another x-session

Tags: linux, mount, xorg, usb, freebsd

I have FreeBSD 10.2 installed with Openbox as wm.
When I put flash drive in USB new instance of openbox starts automaticaly.
I don't undestand why.

/etc/rc.conf

```
# Hostname
hostname="dark"  

fsck_y_enable="YES"
background_fsck="NO"
dumpdev="NO"

hald_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
linux_enable="YES"    

fusefs_enable="YES"
devfs_system_ruleset="localrules"

# Sendmail
sendmail_submit_enable="NO"
sendmail_outbound_enable="NO"
sendmail_msp_queue_enable="NO"

# PPP
ppp_mode="ddial"
ppp_profile="rtel"


kld_list="nvidia"
moused_ums0_enable="NO"
moused_ums1_enable="NO"
```

/etc/devfs.rules

```
[localrules=5]
add path 'da*' mode 0660 group operator
add path 'md*' mode 0660 group operator
add path 'ad*' mode 0660 group operator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# pkg info | grep mount
automount-1.5.7
# pkg remove automount
```